# How to debug memory write performance on linux?

Tags: linux, memory, profiling

I have two almost identical processes communicating through shared memory. Every time a process receives message from the other one, it increments a 8 byte usize integer in its own memory mapped file. (Each process have its own file, they don't share it)

For some strange reason, one process is able to perfom the increment operation in 16ns, while the other one needs something like 140ns.

I have no idea how to profile this.

I have a following piece of (rust) code:

```
let t1 = Instant::now();
let offset_ptr = self.index.as_mut_ptr::<AtomicUsize>();
(*offset_ptr).store(self.topic.offset, Ordering::Relaxed);
let t2 = Instant::now();
```

And I measure difference between `t2` and `t1` with following results:

**Process 1**

```
p50: 15.00 ns, p90: 16.00 ns, p99: 94.00 ns, p99.9: 142.00 ns, p99.99: 422.00 ns, p99.999: 504.00 ns
max: 11.97 μs, avg: 16.00 ns
```

**Process 2**

```
p50: 114.00 ns, p90: 320.00 ns, p99: 664.00 ns, p99.9: 1.07 μs, p99.99: 1.45 μs, p99.999: 4.45 μs
max: 10.69 μs, avg: 137.00 ns
```

Any idea what might be causing such a huge discrepancy in a simple memory write access? And how to debug it?

Comment: Most likely process 2's memory is getting paged out, so it has to wait for the page to be read back in from disk. Is process 2 running less frequently, so its memory is more likely to be paged out?

Comment: This google search locates some tools and techniques for debugging this: **linux process paging statistics**

Comment: And at a crude system level, look at `vmstat` output. It can help you determine if you need more RAM.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it doesn't make sense for the memory to be paged out. There are 130GB of free memory in the system and this is just 8 bytes...

Comment: Both processes run in a forever loop for a total of 100 million times.

Comment: I agree that lots of free memory should preclude this, i just can't think of any other likely reason. But "just 8 bytes" is irrelevant, since memory management operates at the page level.

Comment: Yeah, but besides that, I lock the memory with MAP_LOCKED, that should prevent any swapping, shouldn't it?

Comment: Processes have the same scheduling priority? There's got to be something different between them.

Comment: They have same priority and they run in the same numa group.

Comment: They essentially play the ping-pong. Each process responds with 1KB message when it receives message from the other one. The first one sends a message and this creates an infinite cycle of ping-pong. The only difference between them is who sends the message first. For some reason, the first sender happens to be the fast one.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get a concrete answer here. This seems like the kind of thing a handful of Linux OS experts would be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: Post a bounty to get some help? (I thought paging was the problem). Good luck!